# Compare triangles in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to compare two triangles by two point and height.

```
compare_tri( triangle ( point(X1,Y1), point(X2,Y2), H1),
    triangle( point(X3,Y3), point(X4,Y4), H2)) :-
    A1 is ((X2-X1)*(X2-X1)),
    B1 is ((Y2-Y1)*(Y2-Y1)),
    C1 is (A1+B1),
    D1 is (sqrt(C1)),
    S1 is (D1*H1),
    A2 is ((X4-X3)*(X4-X3)),
    B2 is ((Y4-Y3)*(Y4-Y3)),
    C2 is (A2+B2),
    D2 is (sqrt(C2)),
    S2 is (D2*H2),
    (  (S1 < S2)
    -> (S1 is 2), (S2 is 1)
    ;  (S2 is 2), (S1 is 1)
    ),
    write(S1), write('bigger than '), write(S2).
```

but I get the error message 'syntax operator : operator expected'

What's the problem?

Comment: Note that you can't "reassign" (reinstantiate) a variable within a predicate clause. So expression `S1 is 2` will fail unless `S1` happens to already have the value `2` (since you already computed a value for `S1`). Likewise for `S2 is 1`, `S2 is 2`, etc. So once you fix the syntax error that Sergey pointed out, your predicate is likely not going to output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apart the syntax error, already addressed by Sergey, a general advice: attempt to write *reusable* code in first place. It's easier to debug, to read, to remember....

```
triangle_area(triangle(point(X1,Y1), point(X2,Y2), H), S1) :-
 A1 is ((X2-X1)*(X2-X1)),
 B1 is ((Y2-Y1)*(Y2-Y1)),
 C1 is (A1+B1),
 D1 is (sqrt(C1)),
 S1 is (D1*H1).

compare_tri(T1,T2) :-
 triangle_area(T1,S1),
 triangle_area(T2,S2), etc etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be no space between `triangle` and next brace: change `triangle ( point(X1,Y1)` to `triangle( point(X1,Y1)` and the error will be gone.